# How to Manage more than 1000 reference field data in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In my drupal 7 website, i have content type called book and ther is user reference in form field.As there are more than 2000 records as user reference in individual node.Now it is taking time for load node in admin and even if i add more user reference it is not being save in database.

I have done google for custom code / module and found solution as module for load more field, but in drupal 8 only.Unfortunately it is not available for drupal 7.

Any reference or solution would be helpful for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Not really clear how you set up relation between those 2 content type? So book has reference field that references users and one book has more than 2000 users referenced?

Comment: yes, one content type named "Book" has reference field "User reference".

Comment: And howmany books you have there? Maybe you can change logic a bit. Instead of book referencing the user make user referencing a book?

Comment: There are more than 500 book as node in drupal site.it is not possible to assign book from user, because as i mentioned in question there are moe than 1000 student assignning to single book (node)